# will cpu credit for ec2 shared among loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have a loadbalancer and under that have some T3a type ec2 instances. When a scaling activity happens under ASG new instance will be created and it will start with base cpu credit. Is there anyway I can share the CPU credit for instances under the loadbalancer, else new instance will have only lesser credit score.

Any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can share the CPU credit for instances under the loadbalancer

No, there is no such way. If you run out of credits often, don't use credit-based instances, or enable [unlimited mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-unlimited-mode.html). You may also look at ways to optimize your application to use less CPU.